# std::vector and move semantics

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, move-semantics, std

To enable move semantics on a `std::vector` do I need to pass by value; so the compiler will not copy the element but just move them?

Example:

```
class data
{
public:
    void setMyData(vector<string> sourceData)
    {
        private_data_ = sourceData;
    }

private:
    vector<string> private_data_;
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics)

Comment: You probably you just need `void setMyData(const vector<string> & sourceData)`. Here `sourceData` is a constant reference to the vector you pass. There is no copying involved. What does  `setMyData` do with the vector? Mabe this is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/), tu be sure you need to tell us more.

Comment: @Jabberwocky correct me if  I am wrong but if you pass by const reference how can the sourceData be an empty vector if what I want is moving the memory from one object to another because I don't want to copy the vector but simply move it?

Comment: I think I'm getting what you want. Please confirm: : when you call `somedata.SetMyData(somevector);` should `somevector` be empty afterwards?

Answer (score 4):

> to enable move semantics on a C++ stl vector

You have misunderstanding about the move semantic concept.

The [`std::vector` itself is move constructable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) as it has the move constructor defined. You do not need to enable it explicitly, rather use it properly.

In the function

```
void setMyData(vector<string> sourceData)  // copy 1
{
   private_data_= sourceData; // copy 2
}
```

You are doing double copy. You need instead

```
void setMyData(vector<string> sourceData)  // copy 
{
   private_data_= std::move(sourceData); // move
}
```

or you might want

```
void setMyData(vector<string>&& sourceData)  // only accept the rvalue
{
   private_data_= std::move(sourceData); // move
}
```

and for the second case, you call the function

```
setMyData(std::move(sourceData));
```

Comment: Hi for "enable" I meant to take advantage of it, probably  I did not express myself correctly.

Comment: I want to move not copy original vector can be empty after that is not a problem I picked up void setMyData(vector<string> sourceData){private_data_=std::move(pirceData);}

Comment: You should add the const& overload, otherwise you have additional work for non rvalue calls, where there will always be a tempory created vector

Comment: Since the OP did not show his/her intended usage, I would be very cautious with such assumptions plus that I think its bad practice.

Comment: Oh you are right, my apologies, but it is still bad practice.

Comment: @Superlokkus `setMyData(foo)` emptying the `foo` vector is not necessarily bad practice, it depends in the use case. If the `foo` vector is actually no longer needed afterwards, this is the most efficient solution as there is absolutely no copying involved.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend either using 2 overload of that function or even use a generic one:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class data
{
public:
    void setMyData(const std::vector<std::string>& sourceData){private_data_=sourceData;}

    void setMyData(std::vector<std::string>&& sourceData){private_data_= std::move(sourceData);}

    template <typename T>
    void genericsetMyData(T&& source) {private_data_ = std::forward<T>(source);}

    private:
    std::vector<std::string> private_data_;
};

int main() {
    class data a,b,c,d;
    std::vector<std::string> s1,s2; const std::vector<std::string> s3;
    a.setMyData(s1);
    b.setMyData(std::move(s2));
    c.genericsetMyData(s1);
    d.genericsetMyData((std::move(s1)));
    d.genericsetMyData(s3);
}
```

The templated one is a bit more complex since it uses a so called fowarding reference.

Comment: Are you sure? Often I am getting conflicting advice about std::forward vs std::move for forwarding references.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following:

```
#include <utility>

class data
{
public:
    void setMyData(vector<string> sourceData)
    {
          private_data_ = std::move(sourceData);
    }
        
private:
    vector<string> private_data_;
};
```

And to init, you have two ways:

```
vector<string> myStrings{"hello", "i am", "stringies"};
data mydata;

// Type 1: Give ownership
mydata.setMyData(std::move(myStrings)); // not a single copy, but myStrings is empty

// Type 2: Copy
mydata.setMyData(myStrings); // Copy once only, and myStrings is still valid
```

The good thing about this technique is that you don't have to write several overloaded methods, you can choose which way you want to pass your parameter.